# Property and sub-property pairs

Tags: wikidata, sparql

Here are some example records:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11361734

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q74669

I have the following (updated) query:

```
# Script #2
SELECT
    (GROUP_CONCAT(       ?dateYear ; separator = ", ") AS        ?dateYears)
    (GROUP_CONCAT(       ?cooLabel ; separator = ", ") AS        ?cooLabels)
    (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gameENLabel ; separator = ", ") AS ?gameENLabels)       # English
    (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT      ?dataLink ; separator = ", ") AS        ?dataLinks)
WHERE
{
    # types of item
          {?game wdt:P136  wd:Q744038}  # regular RPGs
    UNION {?game wdt:P136 wd:Q1529437}  # tactical RPGs
    UNION {?game wdt:P136 wd:Q1422746}  # action RPGs
    UNION {?game wdt:P136 wd:Q1143132}  # roguelikes
    #?game wdt:P136/wdt:P279* wd:Q744038.   # any class or subclass of role-playing video game, including MMORPGs
    ?game wdt:P31 wd:Q7889.      # instance of video game

    # English label
    ?game rdfs:label ?gameENLabel.
    FILTER(LANG(?gameENLabel) = "en"). # we mainly want English labels

    # wikidata link
    BIND(CONCAT("=hyperlink(\"",replace(replace(STR(?game), "entity", "wiki"), "http", "https"),"\")") AS ?dataLink).       # changes the target of the URL and creates a MS Excel compatible hyperlink
    #BIND(STR(?game) AS ?dataLink).     # faster substitute

    # release date (simple)
    OPTIONAL
    {
        ?game wdt:P577 ?date BIND(YEAR(?date) AS ?dateYear)
        OPTIONAL
        {
            ?game p:P577 ?dateProp.
            ?dateProp pq:P291 ?region.
            ?region wdt:P297 ?cooLabel.
        }
    }
}
GROUP BY $game
ORDER BY asc (?dateYears) ASC (?gameENLabels)
#limit 100
```

However, there are some issues:

1. It is not rendering all "publication dates" when those dates do not also have a "place of publication" sub-property
2. If the "place of publication" is missing, I would like the missing property to be replaced with "???" (or something similar), so that every game has a date/region pair of some sort in the output

Can someone show me how to accomplish this? Thanks!

[edit]

Here is some example *current* output:

```
1983        Ultima III: Exodus  =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2240236")
1983        Ultima: Escape from Mt. Drash   =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4003118")
1983        Universe    =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q7894198")
1983        Wizardry III: Legacy of Llylgamyn   =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q8028765")
1983, 1982, 1978        Beneath Apple Manor =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4887174")
1984        50 Mission Crush    =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q635707")
1984        Gemstone Warrior    =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5530766")
1984        Questron    =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2687236")
1985    JP  Cosmic Soldier  =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q869287")
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2015  JP, AU, JP, AU, JP, AU  Monster Hunter Generations  =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q20856979")
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012    JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP  Phantasy Star Online 2  =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2709892")
```

[edit]

Here is some example *desired* output:

```
2014, 2015, 2017    JP, ??, ??  Game Title =hyperlink("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2709892")
```

Comment: 1. Use nested `OPTIONAL`s. 2. Please paste example output.

Comment: Thanks. You can view the (updated) query and output here: http://tinyurl.com/y9nefmj9

Comment: The output is the same, except that in the `cooLabels` column there is a result for every date, including `??` for missing regions.  For instance: `1985, 1990 \t JP, ?? \t Game Title \t Hyperlink`

Comment: [The order of strings is not specified.](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggGroupConcat) Nobody can guarantee that 1st `?dateYear` corresponds to 1st `?coolLabel` after concatenation.

Comment: This is true even if the place of publication (P291) is a sub-property of the publication date (P577)? Weird. This seems like a serious shortcoming!

Comment: At your own risk: place `BIND (IF(!bound(?cooLabel), "???", ?cooLabel) AS ?coolLabel)` inside the first `OPTIONAL`. Respectively in the projection: `(SAMPLE(?coolLabel) AS ?cooLabels)`.

Comment: Resp in what? I don't understand.

Comment: Projection is a part between `SELECT` and `WHERE`. But this was my mistake, you do not need to replace `group_concat` with `sample`. BTW, see https://jira.blazegraph.com/browse/BLZG-842. However, one could look into query execution plan (adding `&explain` to your SPARQL query) or into Blazegraph source code hoping that two `group_concat`'s are "isomorphic".

Comment: The page you linked to suggests to use sub-selects. Do you think this would work? Is there a good guide on nesting multiple selects?

Comment: A simple guide, rather.